# Accessing GMail API using Service Account, but limited to single mailbox

Tags: gmail-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to set up a Service Account that can access the GMail API, but for security purposes I want it limited to only a single mailbox (I don't want the development team to have full access to all mailboxes in the organization.)

My understanding of how Google handles service accounts and permissions is limited.  I can't seem to find specific details about how this would be set up.  I have set up a service account with client ID and secret. And I have associated that with an API client that has the GMail read-only scope.  But how does that get associated with a specific mailbox? I do see a setting that allows "domain wide delegation", which seems concerning.

Maybe I'm just not understanding this correctly, but does that mean this service account can now read the contents of all mailboxes in the GSuite account?

How do I make sure this service account is limited to the one mailbox I want it to access?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about user impersonation using the service account. I am afraid that it is not possible to limit the access that the service account can have. The only possible limitations is related to the creations of credentials on the project and things like that, but if a service account has domain wide delegation to do user impersonation, then it is not possible to set up limitations to it.

You can find more info about the possible limitations here https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts

Comment: Thanks for that info. But it seems that accessing the GMail API at all won't work unless we have the domain wide delegation enabled. So it seems that its all or nothing?  That seems very odd Google would do that.

Comment: You are correct, it would be all or nothing. I am afraid that there are no other options available due to how the service accounts work in GCP.